# What exactly is the OIS Black VOL?

Tags: volatility, black-scholes, discounting

While poking around in Bloomberg I stumbled upon the following data set: *EUR SWPT BVOL OIS* for various maturities.

Obviously OIS must suggest OIS-discounting but how is it related to the Black-Implied-Volatility ? Does one simply use the OIS-rate instead of the LIBOR rate as the risk-free reference rate when inverting Black's Formula ?

Comment: Have you tried <HELP>  ? I know it sounds stupid but it is often very effective.

Comment: I agree that this is volatility implied by using OIS as a r.f. rate. Since the crises, there is a push to replace LIBOR with OIS as the "true" risk free rate, so this is probably one of the results.

Comment: Agree with DatamineR, please see my answer to another question: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/11400/why-is-usd-libor-used-for-usd-denominated-securities

Comment: okey - could perhaps someone convert his/her comment into a genuine answer (perhaps with a reference to some OIS related papers)  :D

Comment: OIS is used via dual-curve stripping in the inversion to produce Black vols.  The alternative is LIBOR vols.  Black vol is the alternative to Normal (Bachelier?) vol.  It's not as simple as using the OIS numbers, one needs to re-derive the pricing formulae in the presence of multiple curves etc via no-arbitrage. FINCAD wrote a good primer paper on it.

Comment: @experquisite are LIBOR-vols still quoted ? I do use a LIBOR-Market model and I don't know whether OIS Black vols are compatible. Do you have a link to the FINCAD paper ?

Comment: You wouldn't want to drop OIS Black vols into a LIBOR market model which is modelling LIBOR, but you would if you were modelling OIS with LIBOR on top as a deterministic (or stochastic) basis.  http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2311745 Fabio Mercurio has written some papers on extending LMM for joint OIS/FRA modelling.

Comment: And to answer your first question, some people still quote LIBOR vols, but most caps and swaptions seem to be quoted on an OIS dual-curve-stripped basis.  On Bloomberg, they probably tick out both OIS and LIBOR flavors of vols for all the main swaption points, so you shouldn't have a problem as long as you use the compatible vol for your model.  A good test would be to see how well your LMM recovers the caplet/swaption prices that go into your terminal vol cube, if there's a disconnect between LIBOR vs OIS or Black vs Normal, your prices should be way off.

Comment: @experquisite This is what I thought. As a follow up  an extension to OIS/FRA modelling is a viable step. Right now I only have a standard LIBOR-Model in place. By the way you more or less answered my questions - just copy paste it as answer bleow ;)

Comment: Just find the LIBOR vols, there should be tickers for them too.  VCUB is the function for configuring your IR cube, and if you hover over the points on the front page which is the post-interpolation data, after setting the dropdown to LIBOR, you should see the tickers for all those points.  They don't quite follow a pattern so you have to double-check them all.  Depending on where you sit, you might have your firm's contributed vols that you should be using instead, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reformatting for an answer:

- OIS (vols) - vols backed out of/for pricing in the presence of multiple curves
- LIBOR (vols) - vols backed out of/for pricing in the 'old' way where discount=forward and basis is negligible
- Black (vols) - Black-76 inverted volatilities
- Normal (vols) - Normal/Bachelier (?) inverted volatilities

FINCAD primer on the 'new curves math': http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2311745

One would not want to drop an OIS vol into an old LIBOR Market Model, but Fabio Mercurio and others have extended LMM to encompass multiple curves with deterministic or stochastic basis functions. http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1621547

Various parties quote vols both coming from a LIBOR- or an OIS- space, the Bloomberg function VCUB fits a volatility surface and interpolates and ticks out vols in both OIS- and LIBOR- spaces.  Hovering over the various grid points on the various pages of VCUB should be a good place to start for pulling in vols into your own LMM model.  A good test of whether you are using the right vols in the right places (and of everything else in your pipeline) is to try and recover the prices/premia of caplets/swaptions that you initially fed into VCUB.  And as others have mentioned, being persistent on <HELP> can quickly get you in touch with some very knowledgeable people.

Comment: I also found the Mercurio paper you mentioned: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1621547

Comment: perhaps you could add to your answer :)

Comment: Do you knoe whether there is a way to convert an OIS vol the standard LIBOR-one ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but I am not aware of a easy way - the only way I am aware of is to price all the swaptions with the OIS vol to get their premium, then restrip them back to LIBOR vols.

EDIT: that said, I don't know why you would need to, BBG has all the Libor vols too.  EUSV011 Curncy vs EUVE11 Curncy for instance (LIBOR vs OIS)